# Does a matrix with an even number of positive eigenvalues have a principal submatrix with an odd number of eigenvalues with a positive real part?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $A$ (not necessarily symmetric) that has a positive even number of eigenvalues with a positive real part (they may be positive or complex). Does that imply that $A$ must have a principal submatrix with an odd number of eigenvalues with a positive real part?

Comment: Zero is also an even number. So, $-I$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Oh you are right! I forgot to say that with even I mean even and positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Random counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{-1&-2&1\\ 0&-1&-2\\ -2&1&0}.
$$
The real parts of its eigenvalues are $-2.2030,0.1015$ and $0.1015$. The real parts of the eigenvalues of the principal $1\times1$ or $2\times2$ submatrices of $A$ are $0,-1$ or $-\frac12$.